# How to add and remove classes simultaniously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, animation

I want to add and remove 3 classes in one time in angular jqLite or jQuery.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
$(element).addClass('x')
$(element).addClass('y')
$(element).removeClass('z')
```

Doing this is not efficient becuase

1. it updates the DOM 3 times
2. it isn't consistant because sometimes it doesn't do it in the order I want it (removing the class z before adding the class x for example)

I'm searching for a way to update the dom in one time. Before I write my own method like this one and try to implement it with RegExp

```
$(element).updateClass({add: ['x','y'], remove: ['z']}
```

I was wondering if there is already a solution that I was missing that is easier and will give me the control I want over class manipulation.

Comment: take a look at the [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function. `$(element).toggleClass('x y z')`

Comment: `toggleClass` is all you need. You wont need to check if class is to be added or removed. Toggle class will take care of it.

Comment: if this is in angular should be using `ng-class`

Answer (score 8):

I originally posted this as a comment,
but since you are receiving wrong answers, i'll post it here too.

`$(element).toggleClass('x y z');`

Comment: That's a nice solution I didn't think about. BUT the thing is I don't know if Z is there or not. I can ask the dom ($(element).hasClass('z') ? $(element).toggleClass('x y z') : $(element).toggleClass('x y'). but that's another DOM request.

Comment: @avrahamcool the service I'm writing is managing several states on the directive (x y z) and sometimes I don't care if z is there or not but I want it to be removed anyway. I can set a variable in my service (var currentlyActiveClasses = 'x y') and by keeping it updated I will not need to ask the dom 'hasClass()' questions - then I will have full control whether to toggle this or that class. but since it turns out to be a very specific issue - before I implement it I'm searching for simpler solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) attribute:

```
<p ng-class="{x: if_x, y: if_y, z: if_z}">text</p>
```

In your controller, set `$scope.if_x` to true to enable class `x`, and so on.

The whole point of using Angular is to avoid setting DOM attributes in your code, and to instead use Angular attributes to control the DOM.

Comment: That's a good point. thought I don't think I can use ng-class because if I use it in my directive it will collide with the ng-class that another user might add to the direcive. maybe I can investigate the use of ngClass in other ways

Comment: The question was about jQuery, not Angular

Comment: This question has the `angularjs` tag and it asks about using angular jqlite or jQuery.  If the environment uses Angular, you might as well use it the way it's intended.

Answer (score -1):

$(element).addClass('x').removeClass('y');

Comment: This is wrong because it manipulates the DOM 3 times and I want only one DOM manipulation

Answer (score -1):

**Angular solution**

Set class to a variable:

```
<div class="{{myclass}}"></div>
```

Then simply update the variable to what you want

```
$scope.myclass = "x y";
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution via script (a.k.a element.doSomething()) and not the declarative way

Answer (score -2):

$(element).switchClass('z', 'x y', 0);

[documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/)

Comment: requires jQueryUI library